# Did I Solve These Population Questions Correctly?

Tags: statistics

I was hoping that someone could check over my solutions 1a, 1b to see if they are correct. I would like to make sure that I'm solving these correctly.

[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ysy.png)

a) T and S are not independent of each other due to the fact that when we observe that there is a T gene there is a significantly higher likelyhood that there will also be an S gene (90%) whereas if there is no T gene then it is far less likely that the S gene will appear (30%).

b) The probability that someone will have both the (S && T) gene is .27 (30%*90%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a), you are correct. For a more formal proof, recall that S and T are independent if and only if
$$P(S\cap T) = P(S)P(T).$$
Here $P(S\cap T) = 0.27$, $P(T) = 0.3$, and $P(S) = 0.3\cdot 0.7 + 0.9\cdot 0.3 = 0.48$, so that $P(S)P(T) = 0.144\ne P(S\cap T)$. (Here $0.3\cdot 0.7$ represents the probability of having S but not T, and $0.9\cdot 0.3$ is the probability of having both S and T).

Part (b) is Bayes' Theorem:
$$P(T\mid S) = \frac{P(S\mid T)P(T)}{P(S)} = \frac{0.9\cdot 0.3}{0.48} = \frac{0.27}{0.48} = 0.5625.$$
This is *not* the same as the probability that a randomly-selected person will have both S and T - that is indeed $0.27$.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. One question I do have is why is P(S) equivalent to .3 in this scenario as well as p(T) equal to .7? Is it because we have decided to use the overall population? How did you decide which one went on top? Sorry, this sounds dumb, I just want to make sure I get it fully.

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote there was wrong. I had S and T backwards. I've edited the formula. In any case: $P(S)$ comes from the computation for part (a). One decides which goes "on top" by using the formula for [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem).

Comment: Okay, thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

For (b), you are correct that this is the probability that someone will have both traits, but this is not what they asked for. You already know they have trait S and they want the probability they have trait T. In other words, they're asking for the conditional probability $P(S\mid T).$ In light of part (a), this should be larger than P(S).